# mediaelement.js choppy playback of mp3 stream using flash fallback

Tags: mediaelement.js

MediaElementJS seems not to be caching enough when using the flash alternative to play our mp3 stream on every browsers that don't natively support mp3 and the playback is choppy, pausing and hitting play again usually solves the problem.
Any setting I could tweak to get it working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Mediaelements.js has no cache for itself. You need to tweak the cache in the [Flash Plugin Web Storage Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html).